# How kill a process using powershell without getting errors when the process does not exist

Tags: windows, powershell, clamav

I want to kill the nodepad process if it exists. If I use this:

```
PS C:\> get-process -name notepad | Stop-Process -Force
```

I will get an error when the process does not exist.

```
get-process : Cannot find a process with the name "notepad". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-process -name notepad | Stop-Process -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (notepad:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

I feel it should be silent, as it is not an error, the object should be null.

I know I could do:

```
PS C:\> get-process | where { $_.processname -eq 'notepad' } | Stop-Process -Force
```

but I prefer a simple way if it exists. Thanks.

PS: I need to kill the notepad because when I non-interactively install ClamAV, it create the notepad with a user manual. I could not find a way to tell ClamAV not to open the user manual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. This one is simpler and does not prompt any erros if process does not exist.

```
Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking if the notepad process is the one you want first before just force-ending all notepad processes on the system:

```
Try {
    (Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name='notepad.exe'" | 
    Where commandline -like '*\path\to\manual.txt'
    ).Terminate()
}
# Handle "can't call method on null" error:
Catch [System.SystemException] { "Manual.txt process not found, skipping..." }
```

Comment: It is a good idea to check the process. The "process not found" exception should not be needed using pipe.

Comment: @puravidaso `Get-WmiObject` doesn't return an error when no processes are found, but the `Terminate()` method does, so that's what I catch instead.

Comment: Just a nitpick: the Terminate method is not actually raising the exception.  It is the powershell runtime raising the exception when you try to call a method on non-existent object

Comment: Another note, you can do this also without wmi with get-process
`Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object CommandLine -like '*\path\to\manual.txt' | Stop-Process -Force`

Comment: @Daniel `[System.Diagnostics.Process]` objects returned by `Get-Process` do not have a `CommandLine` property, as far as I'm aware only wmi (and/or `Get-CimInstance`) commands add it.

Comment: They do, at least they do in PS7 `Get-Process | Get-Member`

Comment: @Daniel You're right! (I had to upgrade from 7.0.3 to 7.1.3). Note that it's a ScriptProperty that just runs `(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($this.Id)").CommandLine` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

or ...

```
Stop-Process -Name "chrome" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

And if you are using this with **Gitlab** beware that it has a **bug with PowerShell runner**, that you can work around by encapsulation inside parenthesis resulting in:

```
(Stop-Process -Name "chrome" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

source:
[Gitlab powershell issue breaking on ErrorAction](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4480#:%7E:text=to%20wrap%20the-,command,-with%20parenthesis%20to)